# BDD, SpecFlow and Gherkin all together

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have heard of [BDD](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) (Behavior Driven Development) just recently, and I liked the idea. since I work mainly with C# and .NET, I found [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org), then learned that SpecFlow uses [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) and now I feel lost. Where do you find official documentation that tells you everything you need to know about SpecFlow, the same for Gherkin.

In short: is there a book (not blogs and articles) about developing real life (practical) applications using these tools?

Comment: I think you will find (at least in the .Net world) that this area is a little cutting edge to have that many books written on it, mainly because there haven't been that many full lifecycle projects completed yet. However, that doesn't mean that the information isn't there yet its just not in books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official documentation is available on github: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Documentation

Gherkin documentation: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin

Comment: What about Gherkin, where can you find the official syntax, what the language can do, what not, etc ...

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if there are many books out there that covers this. The book: **Pro Agile .NET development with SCRUM** does cover BDD in one of their chapters.

- [http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Development-SCRUM-Professional-Apress/dp/1430235330](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235330)

Personally I have learnt about it through the following articles/ videos:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Brandom-Satrom-BDD-in-ASPNET-MVC-using-SpecFlow-WatiN-and-WatiN-Test-Helpers
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82891/BDD-using-SpecFlow-on-ASP-NET-MVC-Application
- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend The Cucumber Book (http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book).

It's not about C# and SpecFlow but all concepts applies. Loved it

Comment: i have learned that the book is great. but i really need a book specifically about SpecFlow and the .NET framework.

Comment: Don't think that it exists yet. I would read it anyway. I don't know squat about Ruby - and got everything from the book loud and clear.